# Add a separator to a Context Menu bound to models in WPF with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a context menu in WPF with the following constraints:

- Menu items should be bound to a list of models
- The menu may contain separators
- Menu items can have sub menu items
- Menu items may be turned off based on state
- The order of the menu items may not change (i.e. menu item 1 must appear above menu item 2, if present)

I have seen solutions where the view model contains a list of controls, however, this is not an acceptable solution.

The approach I've taken almost works.

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Data.ContextMenuViewModel, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Data.ContextMenuViewModel.MenuItems, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
         Visibility="{Binding CellContextMenuOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubMenuItems}" />
        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsCheckable, FallbackValue=False}" />
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, FallbackValue=False}" />
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
<ContextMenu.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <ccm:MenuItemTemplateSelector>
        <ccm:MenuItemTemplateSelector.SeparatorTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False" Margin="0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ccm:MenuItemTemplateSelector.SeparatorTemplate>
        <ccm:MenuItemTemplateSelector.MenuItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ccm:MenuItemTemplateSelector.MenuItemTemplate>
    </ccm:MenuItemTemplateSelector>
</ContextMenu.ItemTemplateSelector>
```

However, I've discovered that some properties in ItemsContainerStyle and the DataTemplate are mutually exclusive. For example, if I were to add a visibility binding to the items container style, the data template wont be applied at all.

The problem with the solution above is that the MenuItem itself wont collapse based on a binding, I can only get the header to collapse. If I did not need the separators, I could put everything in an ItemContainerStyle and be done with it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"if I were to add a visibility binding to the items container style, the data template wont be applied at all"_ -- I don't understand how that is possible. The data template should be affected only by the type of the data context object; merely adding a binding shouldn't change that. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I've got a bit of egg on my face. I had actually gone ahead and made a separate project previously, as a proof of concept to see if this would fit into our application, and had run into this "problem." I even showed another developer how if I added the visibility Snoop would show the MenuItem as having no visual subtree. But I can't seem to reproduce my issues. Everything is working.